# addAll if collection is non empty

Tags: java, lambda, collections

Is there any way to stop addAll in case the collection is empty? I want to only add

```
departments = new HashMap<>();

faculty.forEach(faculty-> {
List<String> facultyStaff = get list by some operation ;
    departments.computeIfAbsent(departmentKey, value -> new ArrayList<>())
               .addAll(facultyStaff);
}
```

So in the above code, I want to :

1. create an entry in `departments` if `facultyStaff` is not empty
2. Add `facultyStaff` only if its non-empty

Because departments will be used further and I want to avoid `NullPointer` , `ArrayIndexOutOFBound` exception there.

Comment: in this block, how about an `if` check? or else mostly using `filter` via streams

Comment: if check I Can do. But I am looking for any java 8 API if possible

Comment: Are you getting `facultyStaff` from each `faculty`?  How `department` and `departmentKey` are related to `faculty`?  Can you provide more relevant details?

Comment: `if` statements are valid Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming departmentKey is retrieved from Faculty object, we can rewrite your logic using Java 8 streams.

```
final Map<String, List<String>> departments = faculty.stream()
                .map(fac -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(fac.getDepartmentKey(), this.getFacultyStaff()))
                .filter(entry -> !entry.getValue().isEmpty())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue));
```